# bash command(sed) to remove XML Node

Tags: sed

I'm trying to create Bash command which delete a particular node in XML if it contains a string starting with particular few characters

For e.g.
if my XML is like this:

```
  <X>
   <Y> abc... </y>
   <Y> trf... </y>
   <Y> abc... </y>
  </X>
```

then I've remove all such Y nodes which have values starting with abc... string

In the end, it should remain just like below:

```
<X>
   <Y> trf... </y>
 </X>
```

I was searching and found, 'sed' commmand does something similar with help of regular expressions. Was trying to read various other similar questions on this site and tutorials but getting overwhelmed

I know, asking for kind-of spoon feeding but please suggest if something can be easily done for this as I've just next few hours available before I've to start associated activity!

Also is there easy tutorial on 'sed' as finding learning and understanding it little complex ..whatever I found till now on net.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to use awk then , following command can be used to print those line which does not contains abc in it.

```
 awk '!/<Y> abc/' xml
 <X>
   <Y> trf... </y>
  </X>
```

or

```
awk ' /<X>/,/<\/X>/  {if($0 !~ "<Y> abc") print $0}' xml
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
  <X>
   <Y> abc... </y>
   <Y> trf... </y>
   <Y> abc... </y>
  </X>

$ sed '/<Y> abc/d' ip.txt 
  <X>
   <Y> trf... </y>
  </X>
```

- `/<Y> abc/` match a line containing the pattern `<Y> abc`
- `d` command to delete the matching line
- can also use `grep -v '<Y> abc' ip.txt`

**Further reading:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info
- [How can I replace a string in a file(s)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files)